# [SPRINGBOOT]: Swagger hates *both* HATEOAS dependency _and_ upgrading

Tags: spring-boot, maven, swagger, spring-hateoas, springfox

I have to build a REST service on SpringBoot. My team uses [Swagger](https://swagger.io/solutions/api-testing/) for API testing, so my starter `pom.xml` file has relevant dependencies:

```xml
  <dependencies>

        <!-- =========== Spring Boot Dependencies =========== -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ================= Spring Data JPA ==================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ================ Swagger =============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Right now there's only one simple HTTP controller, no data is even being served:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getHello() {
        return new  ResponseEntity<>(
                new ResponseMessage(ResponseMessage.SUCCESS,
                        "Successfully hit rest service",
                        "Hello user"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

while my Swagger configuration is:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.company.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

The application runs and a visit to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` is fruitful:
[image: My Swagger UI output]

Unfortunately, I noticed that incorporating the HATEOAS dependency:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.hateoas/spring-hateoas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version> <!-- Same results for 1.1.2.RELEASE -->
</dependency>
```

causes the project to crash, with the rather verbose output:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.company.config.Application.main(Application.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@368239c8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:718) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1012) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:194) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:170) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:163) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.lambda$updateTypesIfNecessary$2(BeanTypeRegistry.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:114) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:265) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:254) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:196) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:116) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/UriComponentsContributor
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.UriComponentsContributor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 50 common frames omitted

2020-10-11 16:50:21.499  INFO 10692 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7d446ed1: startup date [Sun Oct 11 16:50:20 EDT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-10-11 16:50:21.500  WARN 10692 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@368239c8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:718) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:419) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:910) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:896) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:882) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:831) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:344) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.company.config.Application.main(Application.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/UriComponentsContributor
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.UriComponentsContributor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Replacing the two dependencies in the `pom.xml` with

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-boot-starter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

unfortunately did not work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to you `springfox-boot-starter` dependency and replace your `@EnableSwagger2` to `@EnableOpenApi`

```
@Configuration
@EnableOpenApi
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.company.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

**Note** Swagger ui will be availble to `{host}:{port}/{contextPath}/swagger-ui/index.html` url

Comment: @Jason, Have you tested above suggested answer?

Comment: I did, and the project builds and runs with the `springfox-boot-starter` *and* `spring-hateoas` dependencies. Unfortunately, accessing `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` through my browser gives me a `WhiteLabel Error Page` that essentially wraps around a 404. The exact text is: 

_"This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Oct 15 10:16:11 EDT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)"._

Am I perhaps doing something wrong w.r.t the URL?

Comment: @Jason, Your swagger will be available at `/swagger-ui/index.html` in your case it will be `localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`

Comment: Still getting a 404, unfortunately. I have tried changing the URL to 
`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`, `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/swagger-u.html` (since the class I mentioned above has the `String` `"swagger-ui.html"` hardcoded),, but no dice. To be precise, Spring's logger warns that the GET requests from the browser are not handled properly: I  am getting stuff such as `No mapping for GET /swagger-ui/index.html` or `No mapping for GET /swagger-ui/swagger-ui.html` etc. :(